# Javascript/Jquery Remove and Add 'onmouseover' event on setinterval?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-8

I am creating a webpage seating plan and I want to be able to make an area tag blink every 1 or 2 seconds just to make it easier to see where an individual sits.

The only thing is, I am using Mapper.js (http://www.netzgesta.de/mapper/) which is a highlighting tool, however there is no way that this Mapper.js can be set to blink when i click on an 'area' tag.

I use a onmouseover event which activates a javascript function to display or highlight the area tag. So is there any way i can make the area tag blink?

The code below is what im using:

```
<area class="noborder icolor000000 blink" coords="507, 3, 647, 161" href="#cp66" shape="rect" onmouseover="setAreaOver(document.getElementById('cp66'),'mapImage_canvas','0,0,0','0,0,0','0.33',0,0,0);null">
```

The 'onmouseover' is what I am trying to remove and add every second to create the blink effect on a set interval. I understand this is a complicated way to do it but i don't think there is any other way.

I need this blink effect to work In **Internet Explorer 8** if possible. The code works to display the highlighting effect but the highlighting just stays on until i move the mouseout of the area tag.

Any help or advice would be appreciated, hope this makes a little sense of what im trying to do
many thanks

Comment: IE8 supports the always great blink tag

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use `setInterval` and `clearInterval` like so :

```
<script>
var area_timer = null;
function area_hover() {
    var hover = false;
    area_timer || (area_timer = setInterval(function() {
        if (hover = !hover) {
            // apply hover style here
        } else {
            // apply normal style here
        }
    }, 500));
}
function area_nohover() {
    clearInterval(area_timer);
    area_timer = null;
    // apply normal style here
}
</script>
<area onmouseover="area_hover()" onmouseout="area_nohover()" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the document.getElementById("youridhere").setAttribute("attributenamehere","value here")

Put that in a timer and have it change the attribute to what you want that way.

Let me know if this works for you or if you need more detail.